# How can I uninstall Jupyter Notebook if I don't know the package manager?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, homebrew, uninstallation, package-managers

I am having troubles with running Jupyter Notebook and want to reinstall it.

When I run `which jupyter`, I get `/opt/homebrew/bin/jupyter`.

However, trying to run `brew uninstall jupyter` yields `Error: No such keg: /opt/homebrew/Cellar/jupyter`.

Indeed, when I type `ls -l /opt/homebrew/bin/jupyter` I get `-rwxr-xr-x  1 my_username  admin  247 Feb 20 11:34 /opt/homebrew/bin/jupyter`,
showing that the directory above is an actual executable file and not a symlink.

Trying to uninstall it with pip also doesn't work: Running `pip uninstall jupyter jupyterlab jupyter-notebook` yields

```
WARNING: Skipping jupyter as it is not installed.
WARNING: Skipping jupyterlab as it is not installed.
WARNING: Skipping jupyter-notebook as it is not installed.
```

and same for `pip3`.

What is the safest way to uninstall jupyter in this case?

---

In case it matters, `sw_vers` gives

```
ProductName:        macOS
ProductVersion:     14.2.1
BuildVersion:       23C71
```

Comment: you can go here: https://jupyter.org where you can try it in the browser or install it.

Comment: What is the output of `brew doctor`?